# no suitable method found for setListData(Object[])

Tags: java

I have a problem with this code, and I'm getting 1 error and 1 warning when I try to compile it. the error is:

```
MarcoSeleccionMultiple.java:43: error: no suitable method found for setListData(Object[])
```

and the warning is:

```
MarcoSeleccionMultiple.java:13: warning: [serial] serializable class MarcoSelecc
ionMultiple has no definition of serialVersionUID
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
// PruebaSeleccionMultiple.java
// Pruebe de MarcoSeleccionMultiple.java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PruebaSeleccionMultiple
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        MarcoSeleccionMultiple marcoSeleccionMultiple = 
            new MarcoSeleccionMultiple();

        marcoSeleccionMultiple.setDefaultCloseOperation( 
            JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        marcoSeleccionMultiple.setSize( 350, 140 ); // establece el tamaño del marco
        marcoSeleccionMultiple.setVisible( true ); // muestra el marco
    } // fin de main
} // fin de la clase PruebaSeleccionMultiple
```

This is other class:

```
// MarcoSeleccionMultiple.java
// Copiar elementos de un objeto List a otro
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MarcoSeleccionMultiple extends JFrame
{
    private JList<String> listaJListColores; // lista para guardar los nombres de los colores
    private JList<String> listaJListCopia; // lista en la que se van a copiar los nombres de los colores
    private JButton botonJButtonCopiar; // botón para copiar los nombres seleccionados
    private final String[] nombresColores = { "Negro", "Azul", "Cyan",
        "Gris oscuro", "Gris", "Verde", "Gris claro", "Magenta", "Naranja",
        "Rosa", "Rojo", "Blanco", "Amarillo" };

    // constructor de MarcoSeleccionMultiple
    public MarcoSeleccionMultiple()
    {
        super( "Listas de selección múltiple" );
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() ); // establece el esquema del marco

        listaJListColores = new JList<String>( nombresColores ); // contiene los nombres de todos los colores
        listaJListColores.setVisibleRowCount( 5 ); // muestra cinco filas
        listaJListColores.setSelectionMode( 
            ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION );
        add( new JScrollPane( listaJListColores ) ); // agrega lista con panel de desplazamiento 

        botonJButtonCopiar = new JButton( "Copiar >>>" ); // crea botón para copiar
        botonJButtonCopiar.addActionListener( 

            new ActionListener() // clase interna anónima
            {
                // maneja evento de botón
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evento )
                {
                    // coloca los valores seleccionados en listaJListCopia
                    listaJListCopia.setListData( listaJListColores.getSelectedValuesList().toArray() );
                } // fin del método actionPerformed
            } // fin de la clase interna anónima
        ); // fin de la llamada a addActionListener

        add( botonJButtonCopiar ); // agrega el botón copiar a JFrame

        listaJListCopia = new JList<String>(); // crea lista para guardar nombres de colores copiados
        listaJListCopia.setVisibleRowCount( 5 ); // muestra 5 filas
        listaJListCopia.setFixedCellWidth( 100 ); // establece la anchura
        listaJListCopia.setFixedCellHeight( 15 ); // establece la altura
        listaJListCopia.setSelectionMode( 
            ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION );
        add( new JScrollPane( listaJListCopia ) ); // agrega lista con panel de desplazamiento
    } // fin del constructor de MarcoSeleccionMultiple
} // fin de la clase MarcoSeleccionMultiple
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine some JavaDoc:

> [setListData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData%28E[]%29)
>
> Parameters: listData - an array of *E* containing the items to display in the list

In your case, this method expects an array of Strings

> [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)
>
> Object[] toArray()

That means, that this method returns an array of object.
And that is why you're getting the mentioned exception. `setListData` expects an array of Strings, but you're giving him an array of Objects.

`List` provides another `toArray` method you should use here: `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`. It expects an array and it will return your list as the same array type you've specified there.

That means, to fix you problem, you should change

```
listaJListCopia.setListData( listaJListColores.getSelectedValuesList().toArray() );
```

to

```
listaJListCopia.setListData( listaJListColores.getSelectedValuesList().toArray(new String[1]) );
```

You could also use `new String[0]` but this could cause another warning.

And now to your warning:

This warning means, that the class `MarcoSeleccionMultiple` implements the interface `Serializable`, because it extends the class `JFrame` which is serializable due to the extended class `Component`.
To fix that warning, include the variable `serialVersionUID` in your class. For example:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Your IDE should be able to generate a `serialVersionUID` for you. Read this JavaDoc for more information about that variable: [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).